# Why won't this div animate?

Tags: jquery

I have added some animation using jquery but it's not working:

```
$('.test-container').click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(119, 119, 119)');
$(this).animate({right: '50%', opacity: 0.3}, 1000);

})
```

Here is the jfiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/eJhdm/2/

Am I doing something obviously wrong here? I can't see it.

Comment: It animates when *I* click on it...if it helps, I'm running Chromium 17 on Ubuntu 11.04..?

Comment: What is your browser? I am using chrome

Comment: I am using chrome 17.0.963 in windows vista. I am confused.

Comment: No; sorry, I'm a moron...I saw the colour-change and the opacity animating, but I didn't realise, until a few moments ago, that the `div`'s position was also meant to change. [@haltabush's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9861710/82548) is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a position to the div.

```
<div class="test-container" style="/*other CSS*/ position:absolute;">testtt</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3HhWx/

Comment: You're absolutely right; I saw the colour-change and the opacity animation; but I didn't realise it was meant to move the div itself as well. I'm an idiot...but +1! (and please forgive the edit, but it's best to give the example code *here*, and use external resources to demonstrate that code). It's worth noting that using `position: relative;` would *also* work. Depending on the desired end-result.

Comment: Yes, position:relative should work better inside a context, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="test-container" style="position: relative;width:100px; height:100px">testtt</div>​
```

add "position: relative;" to the style to give it some wiggle room ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Misspelling is programmers first worst enemy.

you forgot `;` after `})`

http://jsfiddle.net/eJhdm/13/

Actually there was no `position` defined for the div in question.

Comment: Still not animating for me in that fiddle. I am using chrome 17.0.963. What is going on...

Comment: Excellent that worked. I am curious though, why was this working for everyone else and they didn't have to specify a position in the jsfiddle?